# how to get list of my application forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

How can I get all of my application forms, actually I don't want opened forms like following

```
Application.OpenForms
```

But, I need to have all of the forms names for example in ComboBox ??!!

Comment: The question makes little sense.  To get the Name property of a Form derived class, you first have to create an instance of it.  When you do, that form will be a member of the OpenForms collection.  You say you don't want to use that, for mysterious reasons, the only other thing you could do is retrieve the *type name* of a form.  Iterate Assembly.GetTypes().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code to enumerate a list of all your Types (classes) in your solution's namespace, from which you should be able to filter down to a list of your forms:

```
using System.Reflection;
private Type[] GetTypesInNamespace(Assembly assembly, string nameSpace)
{
    return assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => String.Equals(t.Namespace, nameSpace, StringComparison.Ordinal)).ToArray();
}
```

Usage:

```
Type[] typelist = GetTypesInNamespace(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "YourNamespaceHere");
for (int i = 0; i < typelist.Length; i++)
{
    if (typelist[i].IsSubclassOf(typeof(Form))) {
           Console.WriteLine(typelist[i].Name); // Only forms will be written here
    }
}
```

Go after the `typelist` array. This will contain all your solution's types, from which you can get just the forms.

Comment: I Used "System.Windows.Forms" and "Form" also "Forms" but anyone didn't worked for me

Comment: @franchescototti: I edited my answer to show you how to get just the forms from the list.

Comment: It work's but only retrieves existed forms in root ,actually I have other forms in Folder1 ,Folder2 that this code couldn't retrieves them !!!??? @C-Pound Guru

Comment: Check the namespace of the form. If it's different (it includes the folder name) then you'll need to do multiple calls for each namespace.